# Fermi surface of a spherical nanoparticle

Tags: solid-state-physics, nanoscience, fermi-energy

Assume to have a spherical nanoparticle of a metal whose Fermi surface in the crystal is a sphere (I think those are the metals having very symmetric crystals). Would then the Fermi surface be spherical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would not be a Fermi surface. That is a concept for an infinite metal.

Free electrons in a small spherical box would have wave functions with a shell structure and quantum numbers similar to neutrons or protons in nuclear physics.